# TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'theText'

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I'm making a small PyQt4 application and so far I have this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)

        self.text = QtGui.QLabel('Text to be changed')
        self.text2 = QtGui.QLabel('Also to be changed')


        self.textCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        self.textCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(self.check(self.text))
        self.show()

    def check(self, state, theText):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            theText.setStyleSheet("color: pink")
        else:
            theText.setStyleSheet("color: black")

def main():
    q = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(q.exec())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is, my .connect line doesn't seem to want to recognize the parameter I pass into it and I'm not sure why. I can't reference the text directly in the function as I would like to pass many QLabel arguments to it hence I made a theText parameter. I'd appreciate any help.

Version that works without parameters:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)

        self.text = QtGui.QLabel('Text to be changed')
        self.text2 = QtGui.QLabel('Also to be changed')


        self.textCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        self.textCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(self.check)

        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.text)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.textCheckBox)
        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.show()

    def check(self, state):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.text.setStyleSheet("color: pink")
        else:
            self.text.setStyleSheet("color: black")

def main():
    q = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(q.exec())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It seems that you missed out the `state` argument in the line `self.textCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(self.check(self.text))`.

Comment: I'm not so sure that needs to be passed in. My early version of the function was working without that being passed in.

Comment: But you have defined the `check` method to require it to be passed in.

Comment: Perhaps your early version of the function did not have that argument or had it default to something else?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes but if you check this example you'll see that he doesn't pass it in either http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/widgets/. This was what my early version was like.

Comment: @MoonCheesez The early version did have the argument but I'm not sure about whether it defaulted to something.

Comment: That code doesn't have a `check` method, so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The equivalent to my check method would be stateChanged in that example. Do you see he doesn't pass in a 'state' parameter when he calls it?

Comment: Well once again that method is not shown in that example, so we can't know how it is defined, but it seems likely that it does not expect a state parameter, *but yours does* because *that's how you wrote it*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Check my edit. check() still has a state parameter and when I call it I don't pass an argument in.

Comment: But now you're not calling it, you're just passing it to `connect`. That is not remotely the same thing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Whether I'm semantically calling it the right thing is a different issue. The fact is it doesn't appear like I need to pass in state to .connect. If this is such a simple issue why don't you open IDLE and quickly fix it for me, otherwise you're contributing nothing now.

Comment: I"m sorry you feel that way. What you call a "semantic" issue is **an absolutely fundamental distinction**; you are doing two very very different things in those two pieces of code and you need to understand that before you or anyone can fix your problem, as it is key to why one works and one doesn't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Apologies. It seems I did need to pass in state.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setFixedSize(500, 300)

        self.text = QtGui.QLabel('Text to be changed')
        self.text2 = QtGui.QLabel('Also to be changed')


        self.textCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        test = self.textCheckBox.checkState()
        self.textCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.check(self.textCheckBox.checkState(), self.text))

        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.text)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.textCheckBox)

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)

        self.show()

    def check(self, state, theText):

        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.setWindowTitle("test")
        else:
            theText.setStyleSheet("color: black")

def main():
    q = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(q.exec())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Seem to have fixed it. Not too sure why it works though.